# Trying to use the condition in a case when expression as the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `CASE` expression and for one of the `WHEN` clauses, I'm selecting data from a table and checking if it exists. If it exists, I want to return one of the columns from that row in the `THEN` expressions

```
case 
    --a few when statements
    when name = 'aiden'
    THEN
        case
            when (select top 1 * from tableA a where [list of conditions]) = 1 and  (select top 1 value from tableB b where [list of conditions]) = 1
            THEN b.value -- this lines throwing "the multi-part identifier "b.value" could not be bound."
        else
            --do some existing logic
    Else
    --other logic
end as data
```

The issue I have though is SQL MS returns an error message under the b.value stating it cannot be bound. Is this because the actual referenced table is in a when statement and how would I be able to get around this if it's possible?

Comment: It's `CASE` expression there is no `CASE` statement

Comment: Instead of putting subqueries in the case expression (there is no such thing as a case statement), consider adding joins to tableA and tableB then use those refs in your case expression.

Comment: `SELECT top 1 FROM...`? Where's the column?

Comment: @Larnu - sorry corrected that.

Comment: Rather than nesting case statements, you can use an AND.  
when name = 'aiden' AND (SELECt…..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *WHEN* clause of the `CASE` expression has its own scope, so the subqueries you have executed there are inaccessible to the *THEN* clause.

Looking at it another way, the `CASE` expression forms part of the `SELECT` list, so any field referenced in it must appear in the `FROM` clause.